# Como fazer um link com cada item de uma lista de retorno da API?

Tags: javascript, react, api, axios, link

Estou fazendo um projeto com react e fiz uma página de campo de busca que me trás uma listagem de nomes, até essa parte ok. Porém preciso que cada nome desse da lista seja um link que me leve para uma informação específica desse "cliente". Fiz alguma tentativas e apenas consegue fazer um link que me leva para todas as respostas de uma vez, não a resposta específica. Alguém saberia me informar o que estou fazendo de errado?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

 export default function Responsible() {
   const [responsaveis, setResponsaveis] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => {
   let nomeResp = localStorage.getItem('nomeResp');
   nomeResp = JSON.parse(nomeResp);
   setResponsaveis(nomeResp);
   }, []);

   return (
    <>
       <h1 className="title2">Responsáveis</h1>
       <ul>
       {responsaveis.map((resp) => (
       <li>
       <Link to="/DetalhesResponsavel">{resp}</Link>
       </li>
      ))}
   </ul>
  </>
 );
}
```

A página "/DetalhesResponsavel" que era para vir apenas a informação do link do "cliente" que cliquei está assim:

```
   import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

   export default function RespDetails() {
     const [responsaveis, setResponsaveis] = useState([]);
     useEffect(() => {
     let detResp = localStorage.getItem('detResp');
     detResp = JSON.parse(detResp);
     setResponsaveis(detResp);
   }, []);

  return (
   <>
    <h1>Responsável ID :</h1>
     <ul>
      {responsaveis.map((det) => (
        <li>{det}</li>
       ))}
     </ul>
   </>
 );
}
```

O que acontece é que está vindo todas as informações de uma vez, como se toda a lista de nomes fossem um link só e levassem a todas as informações de uma vez.

Answer (score -1):

Olá, o que voce fazer eram dois componentes (ou páginas no caso)

O primeiro gera uma lista com vários links
O segundo deveria ser uma página com informações de cada item da lista, correto?

Se for isso, pensa assim "Como o segundo componente saberia qual informação deveria exibir? De qual item da lista?"

No segundo componente que voce criou em nenhum momento você diz qual item da lista ele deveria exibir, ou seja, ele não consegue identificar. Além disso se você ler a lógica escrita você diz para ele exibir todos os items da lista:

```
{responsaveis.map((det) => (
    <li>{det}</li>
 ))}
```

Uma possivel solução:

Existem diversas saídas para você identificar qual item da lista você quer exibir, uma das saídas poderia ser a seguinte:

No primeiro componente passar o id pelo link:

```
<li>
   <Link to=`/DetalhesResponsavel/${resp.id}`>{resp}</Link>
</li>
```

No segundo componente identificar pelo link:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function RespDetails() {
   const [responsaveis, setResponsaveis] = useState([]);
   const pathname = window.location.pathname;
   const id = pathname.split('/')[-1];
   useEffect(() => {
     let detResp = localStorage.getItem('detResp');
     detResp = JSON.parse(detResp);
     setResponsaveis(detResp);
   }, []);

  return (
   <>
    <h1>Responsável ID :</h1>
     <ul>
      {responsaveis.map((det) => (
        if (det.id === id) {
          <li>{det}</li>
        }
       ))}
     </ul>
   </>
 );
}
```

Nas rotas talvez você tenha que modificar (nao sei como está):

Talvez dê algum erro por ter modificado o link, daí já não sei o que você está usando para relacionar o link com os componentes, mas caso você esteja usando  não utilize "exact path", use apenas o "path"

Tem um exemplo bem parecido que você quer fazer aqui no tutorial do react router:
https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).